# Executing parameterised T-SQL stored procedure in Access vba

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access

I'm getting a "Run time error (13): type mismatch" error when I attempt to execute the below sproc from an after update event in Access.  My sproc has the @Season as nvarchar(max) and @Year as int in the SQL (MSSQL2014).  Any ideas as to the cause?  I've been search all day but no joy as yet.  Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Event_Click()

    Dim cnn1 As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command


    Set cnn1 = New ADODB.Connection
    cnn1.ConnectionString = "<connection string snipped but works OK>"
    cnn1.ConnectionTimeout = 30
    cnn1.Open

vSeason = Me.ComboBox1.Value
vYear = Me.ComboBox2.Value

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = cnn1
    .CommandText = "dbo.StoredProcedure"
    .CommandType = 4
    .CommandTimeout = 0
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Season", adVarChar, adParamInput, vSeason)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Year", adInteger, adParamInput, vYear)

End With

    cnn1.Close
    Set cnn1 = Nothing
```

Would be grateful for any pointers here.  Any further info needed let me know.

Comment: I think `adVarChar`should be replaced with `adVarWChar`.

Comment: ^^ that - the `n` is making the parameter unicode, so you need a unicode parameter. also, is there any reason why `@Season` is `nvarchar(max)`? If you can, make the procedure take a `@SeasonId int`. I'd take a 4000-character input (when the actual need is likely < 50) as a design smell.

Comment: Try to use `Execute` instead `ADODB.Commands`. `cnn1.Execute ("EXEC dbo.StoredProcedure '" & vSeason & "', " & vYear & ";")`

Comment: @Mat's Mug and Zohar - Unfortunately switching to adVarWChar made no difference to the data type error.  With respect to Mat's suggestion of making the Season parameter an int, I could do that, although I'm concerned that vba is not recognising the string parameter to start with :( .

Comment: @HansUp switching the append statements didn't change anything

Comment: @gofr1 Thanks, that achieved an execution in the profiler.  Should solve my problem.

Comment: I am using: cmd.CommandType = adCmdText (which is 1 not 4)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that CreateParameter need size for adVarChar datatype before its value.

try something like:

```
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Season", adVarChar, adParamInput, 200, vSeason)
```

in your code the value vSeason is passed as size parameter,
you are passing a string as integer to CreateParameter,  **this is the type mismatch error**

I hope this helps